# Откуда ofstream берет размер "массива", если передать указатель?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Началось все с того, что мне лень было придумывать название файла и я решил его назвать wchar_t, взятым из свободного участка памяти.

Но вместо ожидаемого имени из 1 символа получилось 10+

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого я попытался вывести указатель, получил указатель в лецо, а не символы (логично), а затем вывел через звёздочку. Получил один char

`cout << (new wchar_t);` -> `cout << *(new wchar_t);`

Логично предположить, что массив обрабатывается иначе, а еще если работать со списком элементов через указатель, то компилятор не знает о количестве выделенных данных. Свои догадки я подтвердил следующими финтами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

16 - это реальный размер двух даблов, а 4 - это размер указателя для чего бы он ни был.

**Вроде бы все логично, но откуда Ofstream берет рандомное количество чаров которое примерно равно 10, а не один чар как обычно?**

Comment: Это называется мусор в памяти, после ее выделения. А `ofstream` продолжает читать данные пока не встретит признак завершения строки `'\0'`, или `L'\0000'`.

Comment: вы ответили на мой вопрос вполне. 
я совершенно забыл про признак конца завершения строки.

Comment: что значит работать со списком элементов через массив, я так и не понел...

Comment: я ошибся и уже сделал правку. 
*через указатель, тоесть юзать ```new double[2]``` вместо ```double[2]```

Comment: "...если работать со списком элементов через указатель..." - о каком "списке" идет речь? Я не увидел в приведенных примерах ни одного списка. В заголовке вопроса упоминается некий "размер массива". О каком "массиве" идет речь? Где вы в ваших экспериментах увидели, что "ofstream берет размер массива"?

Comment: смотрите комментарий выше. выяснилось, что он берет не размер массива, а все чары до ```'\0'```.
под  списком элементов я подразумевал не объект с названием 'список' в с++, а набор элементов.